# Passing unsigned int input attribute to vertex shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math, vertex-buffer

In a typical building of a vertex-array-buffer, I am trying to pass an unsigned int attribute along side other classical ones (vertex, normal, texture coordinates...). However the value of this attribute ends up somehow wrong: I am unsure whether the value is wrong or the attribute is simply not set.

Starting from a simple example, say I have defined the following C++ input structure:

```
struct buffer_data_t
{
    glm::vec3 vertex;
    glm::vec3 normal;
    glm::vec2 texCoords;
};
```

Preparing my vertex array would look like so:

```
// Assume this 'shader.attribute(..)' is working and returns the attribute's position
unsigned int shadInputs[] = {
    (unsigned int)shader.attribute("VS_Vertex"),
    (unsigned int)shader.attribute("VS_Normal"),
    (unsigned int)shader.attribute("VS_TexCoords"),
};

glGenBuffers(1, &glBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, glBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertice.size() * sizeof(buffer_data_t), &vertice[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &glArray);
glBindVertexArray(glArray);
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, glBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(shadInputs[0], 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(buffer_data_t), (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec3) * 0));
    glVertexAttribPointer(shadInputs[1], 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(buffer_data_t), (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec3) * 1));
    glVertexAttribPointer(shadInputs[2], 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(buffer_data_t), (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec3) * 2));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shadInputs[0]);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shadInputs[1]);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shadInputs[2]);
}
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

And the vertex shader inputs would be defined like that:

```
in vec3 VS_Vertex;
in vec3 VS_Normal;
in vec2 VS_TexCoords;
```

Also, for the sake of my example, let's say that I have a texture sampler in my fragment shader, on which to use those input TexCoords:

```
uniform sampler2D ColourMap;
```

**Introducing my issue**

So far so good, with the code above I can render textured primitives successfully. Now I would like to select different colour maps depending on the face being rendered. To do that, I want to introduce an **index** as part of the vertice attributes. Changes are:

C++ data structure:

```
struct buffer_data_t
{
    glm::vec3 vertex;
    glm::vec3 normal;
    glm::vec2 texCoords;
    unsigned int textureId; // <---
};
```

Prepare vertex array:

```
unsigned int shadInputs[] = {
    (unsigned int)shader.attribute("VS_Vertex"),
    (unsigned int)shader.attribute("VS_Normal"),
    (unsigned int)shader.attribute("VS_TexCoords"),
    (unsigned int)shader.attribute("VS_TextureId"),
};

// ...

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, glBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(shadInputs[0], 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(buffer_data_t), (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec3) * 0));
glVertexAttribPointer(shadInputs[1], 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(buffer_data_t), (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec3) * 1));
glVertexAttribPointer(shadInputs[2], 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(buffer_data_t), (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec3) * 2));
glVertexAttribPointer(shadInputs[3], 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(buffer_data_t), (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec3) * 2 + sizeof(glm::vec2))); // <---
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shadInputs[0]);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shadInputs[1]);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shadInputs[2]);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shadInputs[3]);
```

Then the vertex shader defines that new input, and also a 'flat' out

```
in vec3 VS_Vertex;
in vec3 VS_Normal;
in vec2 VS_TexCoords;
in unsigned int VS_TextureId;

...

out flat unsigned int FS_TextureId;
```

Fragment shader adjusted to take the input flat and (again for the sake of the example) the colour map is now an array we can pick from:

```
...
uniform sampler2D ColourMaps[2];
in flat unsigned int FS_TextureId;
...
texture2D(ColourMaps[FS_TextureId], ... );
```

**These changes do not work** specifically because of the Vertex shader input attribute 'VS_TextureId'. I was able to prove this (and to find a workaround), by not using the unsigned int type and instead resort to vec2 (or vec3, works either way). That is:

VS:

```
in vec2 VS_TextureId;
out flat int FS_TextureId;
FS_TextureId = int(VS_TextureId.x);
```

FS:

```
in flat int FS_TextureId;
texture2D(ColourMaps[FS_TextureId], ... );
```

**My assumption**

I am guessing that this is the line at fault, although I cannot figure how/why:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(shadInputs[3], 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(buffer_data_t), (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec3) * 2 + sizeof(glm::vec2)));
```

Note: I checked the result of 'shader.attribute("VS_TextureId")' and it is correct, meaning the attribute in the vertex shader is well defined and found.

Can you see what the problem could be?

Comment: FYI: indices to arrays of opaque types (like samplers) must be dynamically uniform values. And `FS_TextureId` is *not* one (not unless every triangle in the rendering command gets the same value).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to specify array of attributes, with an integral data type, then you've to use [`glVertexAttribIPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) (focus on *`I`* in the middle of the function name), rather than `glVertexAttribPointer`.

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 10.2. CURRENT VERTEX ATTRIBUTE VALUES; page 348](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=369&zoom=100,0,609)

> The **`VertexAttribI*`** commands specify signed or unsigned fixed-point **values
> that are stored as signed or unsigned integers**, respectively. Such values are referred to as pure integers.

> ...

> All other **`VertexAttrib*`** commands specify values that are **converted directly to the internal floating-point representation**.

This means the specification of the vertex attributes has to be:

```cpp
//glVertexAttribPointer(shadInputs[3], 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_FALSE, 
//    sizeof(buffer_data_t), (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec3) * 2 + sizeof(glm::vec2))); 
glVertexAttribIPointer(shadInputs[3], 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
    sizeof(buffer_data_t), (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec3) * 2 + sizeof(glm::vec2)));
```

---

In general what you try to achive doesn't work like this. The index to an array of samplers has to be "dynamically uniform". This means the index has to be the "same" for all fragments (e.g. a constant or a uniform variable).

See [GLSL 4.60 Specification - 4.1.7. Opaque Types
(page 33)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf)

> Texture-combined sampler types are opaque types, declared and behaving as described above for opaque types. When aggregated into arrays within a shader, they can only be indexed with a dynamically uniform integral expression, otherwise results are undefined. [...]

I recommend to use a single `TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` texture, rather than an array of `TEXTURE_2D` textures. See [Texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture).
In this case you can use 3 dimensional floating point texture coordinate.

Comment: Oh dear! Thank you, I knew it had to be something tiny and silly! I will try your fix (although I'm sure it will prove to solve the problem) before marking your answer as accepted. Thank you again!

Comment: @Smoove Sorry, I didn't read the question to the end, I just read down to the vertex specification. Read the comment to your question (of @NicolBolas). What you try to achieve doesn't work like this. I recommend to use a `TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`

Comment: Actually I was confused by @NicolBolas' comment - I just tried to use the IPointer as you suggested and everything works now (as it was before with my workaround) - meaning I am indeed able to pick different textures based on that attribute, within the same rendering pass (of course a given face, aka vertex triplet has the same texture index)

Comment: @Smoove I see. Which hardware and OpenGL version do you use?

Comment: @Smoove Hardware vendors often go beyond the specification, respectively provide extensions, which are not part of the standard (yet). The specification is very clear in this point, It says if `FS_TextureId` is an input variable, then `ColourMaps[FS_TextureId]` is undefined. But note, it doesn't say that it is not allowed to work.

Comment: I am running an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 and I am not sure on how to check my OpenGL version, but my shader explicitly specify 4.5

Comment: @Smoove Ok, I see. This is a state of the art hardware. So possibly that's the reason.

Comment: I see, so not advisable because I have no guarantee basically :)

Comment: @Smoove No, you've no guarantee, by the OpenGL 4.6 standard.